# Mutating function in Julia (function that modifies its arguments)

Tags: julia

How do you define a mutating function in Julia, where you want the result to be written to one of it's inputs.

I know functions exist like `push!(list, a)`, which mutate their inputs but how can I define one of my own using the exclamation mark.

Comment: [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/faq/?highlight=Mutable#functions) is a concise example in FAQs.

Comment: So does that mean this could only happen when the type of variable that needs to be modified in place to be mutable itself?

Comment: @A.Yazdiha yes, that is correct. Note that even if it is mutable and you assign a new value to that variable inside your function (instead of simply mutating it by assigning by index) you'll have a new object on your hands instead.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Well, I'd say this is *mostly* true.  See my response below for a bit of a counter point, if you're willing to use symbols and expressions. : )

Comment: Hahah. Nice! Well, yes, you could also mutate an object by force if you could store new values via unsafe pointer operations (e.g. `unsafe_store!`), but that's totally hacks to bypass intended behaviour, rather than what's supposed to happen, heheh.

Comment: Updating link provided by @Gnimuc: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/?highlight=Mutable#Functions

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `!` is just a convention; it is not a requirement for mutating functions.

Any function can mutate its inputs.
But so that it is clear that it is doing so, we suffix it with a `!`.

The input to be mutated does have to be mutable, though.
Which excludes `String`s, Tuples, `Int64`s, `Float32`s etc.
As well as custom types defined without the `mutable` keyword.

Many types are mutable, like Vectors.
But you do need to be sure to be changing their *contents*,
rather than the *references* to them.

Say, for example, we want to make a function that replaces all elements of a vector with the number 2.
(`fill!(v,2)` is the Base method to do this. But for example's sake)

#### what will work

Changing what `v` contains:

```
function right1_fill_with_twos!(v::Vector{Int64})
    v[:]=[2 for ii in 1:length(v)]
end
```

Which is the same as:

```
function right2_fill_with_twos!(v::Vector{Int64})
    for ii in 1:length(v)
        v[ii]=2
    end
    v 
end
```

#### So what won't work:

is changing thing what that name `v` points to

```
function wrong1_fill_with_twos!(v::Vector{Int64})
    v=[2 for ii in 1:length(v)]
end
```

Which is the same as:

```
function wrong2_fill_with_twos!(v::Vector{Int64})
    u = Vector{Int64}(length(v))
    for ii in 1:length(v)
        u[ii]=2
    end
    v = u 
end
```

The reason you cannot modify immutable variables (like `Int64`s),
is because they don't have contents to modify -- they are their own contents.

This notion that you must change the Content of a variable passed in to a function, rather than change what the name is bound to (replacing the object) is a fairly standard thing in many programming languages. It comes from pass by value, where some values are references.
I've heard it called the *Golden Rule (of References)* in Java

Comment: Golden Rule of References? Never heard of that, are you sure? Not to mention, I don't think Java has "mutable / immutable" objects in the same sense as Julia ...

Comment: The so called "Golden Rule" is not about immutability, it is about changing the content of variables passed by reference, rather than what they are bound. I've editted to clarify.
The name golden rule, may not be in common use -- It might have just been my first year Java lecturer making up a name for it so his students would stop making the same mistakes again and again. In which case it utterly worked, since i still remember it today.

Comment: For mutating a dictionary, you can do something like `foreach(x -> delete!(orig, x), keys(orig))` followed by `merge!(orig, new)` instead of `orig = new`.

Comment: @phyatt  what part of my answr are you suggesting needs to be changed?

Comment: I found your answer and it helped me see where the problem was in my code, but I wasn't dealing with a mutating `Vector`, I was mutating a `Dict`.  So if you wanted to do an example with a Dict mutation, my last comment would get you started.

Comment: @FramesCatherineWhite Great answer! One question though. How can you replace an array with its subarray inside a function, like `v=v[I]` where `I` is a vector of indices? I'm getting `ERROR: DimensionMismatch: tried to assign 4 elements to 12 destinations`.

Comment: @leo please use the question button to ask a new question

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to assign new values to a constant within a function if you're willing to feed that function a symbol corresponding to the constant as an argument, although I think that some might argue that this doesn't satisfy Julia programming best practices:

```
function modify_constant!(constant_symbol::Symbol, other_arg)
    new_val = eval(constant_symbol) + other_arg
    eval(Main, Expr(:(=), constant_symbol, new_val))
end

y = 2
modify_constant!(:y, 3)

julia> y
5
```

Or, if one wanted, a bit more concisely:

```
function modify_constant!(constant_symbol::Symbol, other_arg)
    eval(Expr(:(+=), constant_symbol, new_val))
end
```

For more discussion of a related issue, see this [Github discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2386)

Answer (score 2):

For a struct type, you can use `setfield!(value, name::Symbol, x)` and `getfield(value, name::Symbol)` inside a function.

When you call the function, you need to pass the struct obj/name (value) and the field symbol (name). (x) is the new value for the struct field.