# Julia: change a variable point to a new place in a method

Tags: julia

I'm coding a Linked List that starting with a normal node, end with a Nil Node, here is my code:

```
abstract type LinkedList  end

struct Nil <: LinkedList
end

mutable struct Node <: LinkedList
    value::Any
    nextNode:: LinkedList
end

function append!(headNode::LinkedList, ele::Any)
    if isa(headNode, Nil)
        headNode =  Node(ele, Nil())
        return headNode
    else
        n = headNode
        while !isa(n.nextNode, Nil)
            n = n.nextNode
        end
        n.nextNode = Node(ele, n.nextNode)
        return headNode
    end
end

linkedList() = Nil()
l = linkedList()
```

when I append a element to a empty link, I type

```
l = append!(l, 3)
# l is 3 -> Nil
```

but i want do seem work like this

```
append!(l, 3)
# change l without re-assign l
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi eric and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Let me start with something general. In Julia, you can't reassign a function argument, that is make it point to somewhere else, a new object for example. You can only modify the content of mutable type objects (a vector for example). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294877/2365675 for more details.

Based on this, let's see what your code does. Your `Nil` type is immutable and therefore you can't modify it. You are creating a new Node object in the first branch in `append!` and returning it. `Node` objects are, however, mutable which you exploit in the second branch where you walk down the linked list and modify the last (mutable) node by making it point to a new node instead of `Nil()`. Hence, you are modifying `headNode`, the functions first argument.

I am not precisely sure what you want. I'd suggest to always use an `l = append(l, 3)` approach (no modification of old objects). Also it seems to me that growing the linked list to the left instead of to the right (at the `Nil` end) is easier and cleaner.

In any case, there is a package [DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl) which also contains a [linked list implementation](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl/blob/master/src/list.jl). I suggest you take a look (first 14 lines should be enough) as things should become clearer then.

Comment: Thanks !!! I code linked list according your example, it's work well!
when i l program with c , it could use a pointer which point to header. And i can append a node without reassign a variable. I should change my thinking from c to Julia.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer is satisfying, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will give some reputation to both you and me (the answer er) and will indicate to the community that this issue is solved. Leave it as is if you hope for better answers.