# Having troubles defining a function that can mutate its input

Tags: julia

I have read this:
[Mutating function in Julia (function that modifies its arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293082/mutating-function-in-julia-function-that-modifies-its-arguments)
Based on the solution, I tried to define a function that scales its input (array of numbers).
It throws me this error though: InexactError: Int64(scaled_value)

```
x = rand(1:50,10)
# this function works, but does not modify the original input:
function scale(x)
    ((x .- mean(x))/std(x))
end

10-element Vector{Float64}:
 -1.3752851148380758
  1.1438014816475086
 -0.2859503704118771
 .
 .
```

###### However, this throws me Ineact error msg

[image]

```
function scale!(v::Vector{Int64})
    for ii in 1:length(v)
        v[ii]= (v[ii] - mean(v)) / std(v)
    end
    v 
end
```

###### I figured it has to do with the Float conversion, since when I tried it on a dummy vector [-2,0,2] it worked ok.

```
function scale2!(x)
    z = copy(x)
    z = (x .- mean(x)) / std(x)
    copy!(x,z)
end
y = [2,0,-2]
scale2!(y)
y
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
  0
 -1
```

/=
Something with the Float(either abstract or 64 or whatever) breaks the whole thing.

Comment: The input vector is an integer vector, `Vector{Int}`. Inside the function you try to replace its valued with floats. This works ok for the last case, because -1.0, 0.0 and 1.0 can be exactly converted to `Int`, but it doesn't work in general. Make the input a vector of floats instead.

Comment: Also note that your `scale!` function calculates the mean and std of the entire function for every iteration. That's inefficient, and also probably wrong, since the mean/std value will change each time you change an element value. You should probably calculate mean and std only once, before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Collecting my comments:

Your problem is that the input vector is an integer vector, `Vector{Int}`. Inside the function you try to replace its values with floats. This works ok for the last case, because `-1.0`, `0.0` and `1.0` can be exactly converted to `Int`, but it doesn't work in general. Make the input a vector of floats instead.

Also note that your `scale!` function calculates the `mean` and `std` of the entire function for every iteration. That's inefficient, and also probably wrong, since the `mean`/`std` value will change each time you change an element value. At least, it is different from what is calculated in the original `scale` function You should probably calculate `mean` and `std` only once, before the loop:

```
function scale!(v::Vector{<:AbstractFloat})
    m = mean(v)
    s = std(v)
    for ii in eachindex(v)  # it is not considered good style to use 1:length()
        v[ii] = (v[ii] - m) / s
    end
    return v 
end
```

If you want to use broadcasting (which is the right approach here, imo), you can write:

```
function scale!(v::Vector{<:AbstractFloat})
     v .= (v .- mean(v)) ./ std(v)
end
```

Notice precisely where I put the dots: in front of `=`, in order to overwrite `v`, in front of `-` and `/`. All those are necessary to make the calculations work in-place, and without any allocations. But *not* after `mean` or `std`, because they must work on the entire vector.

In this case there is no need to calculate `mean` and `std` separately, because they will be evaluate before the broadcasting.

Comment: There's a slight improvement using `m = mean(v); s = std(v, mean=m)`, but it's hardly dominant.

Comment: Thanks man. I will read more thoroughly when I get home from work. Thanks for elaborating on this one

Comment: Indeed it worked when i turned the vector into floats. However, I tried to overcome this by adding a line `v = float(v)` but that yield an error. Not sure what's my thoughts about the language being so strict to be honest.. coming from R and Python its a bit of a hassle

Comment: You only need to remember one rule concerning collections (like vector) and vectorization, and that is that you add a dot: `.` to your functions and operators. If you think about it, it doesn't make sense to turn a vector into a float, but it does make sense turning each _element_ of a vector into a float: `float.(v)`. And it works for _every_ function, automatically, with no extra work needed. For someone like me, coming from Matlab where everything is autovectorized, this Julia rule is the single best thing in the language. It makes it _super easy_ to vectorize _everything_.